# Bootstrap equivalent of HTML5Boilerplate's .visuallyhidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html5boilerplate

Is there a Twitter Bootstrap equivalent of HTML5Boilerplate's .visuallyhidden non-semantic helper class?  I can't see anything similar in the CSS files.  The purpose of the .visuallyhidden class is to visually hide it, but make the text available to screenreaders.  Is there a different Bootstrappy approach to achieve the same goal?

```
// HTML5Boilerplate's non-semantic helper class
.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

The related Bootstrap non-semantic helper classes don't achieve the same effect:

```
// Some of Twitter Bootstrap's non-semantic helper classes
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the Bootstrap class `.sr-only` either in your HTML (non-semantic) or as a mixin. Here's the definition:

```
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Added : `white-space:nowrap`

Answer (score 6):

Well,

```
.text-hide {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font: 0/0 a;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

**Edit 2013-11-25**:
In Bootstrap v3.0.1 (as Dean stated correctly in his comment below) `.text-hide` does partly what you want. Earlier than that up to Bootstrap v3 the class name was `.hide-text`.
It's originally meant for image-replacement, therefore it leaves the 'display' property unchanged.

See https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/commit/aa0396eae757 for a full explanation of all properties in this rule, like the wonderful `0/0 a` workaround for CSS validator.

One further reading on the `.hide-text` class:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2362#issuecomment-4501223

There's also an issue filed in Bootstrap with your question:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6452

Comment: And please think about, if it's necessary to put non-semantic classes into source! ;)

Comment: Hi Volker, Actually I use Compass/SASS so I don't use them in a non-semantic way.  I use them as 'mixins' applied to various elements in the CSS (SASS).  Thanks for pointing out the pull-request.  I'll wait till it appears in the Compass plugins I'm using.

Comment: Quote from Bootstrap source: Heads up! v3 launched with with only `.hide-text()`, but per our pattern for mixins being reused as classes with the same name, this doesn't hold up. As of v3.0.1 we have added `.text-hide()` and deprecated `.hide-text()`. So use `.text-hide`.